# Use session in Heroku scheduler

Tags: node.js, session, heroku, scheduled-tasks, gmail-api

I want to be able to delay send email on my heroku/nodejs app.
I know how to use the Heroku Scheduler to delay tasks.
I can then retrieve which emails need to be sent for which user.
But to use the Gmail API I need to retrieve the authenticated user session, and I don't know how to do that.
I am using pg to store the session, but I don't believe it would be specific:

```
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'xxx',
        store: new pgSession({
            conString: config.db.url
        }),
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: { maxAge: 24192000000 }
    }));
```

Comment: To use the Gmail API to send emails, you need the user's OAuth token after prompting for logging in to Google. Are you not storing that? Once you have that, you can send emails later as long as it doesn't expire.

Comment: The session module you have shown here, store's authenticated user's session for YOUR app. If you are already storing which emails need to be sent for which user, you should not have to worry about this.

Comment: @RahatMahbub I think he is saying he doesn't know how to retrieve a specific session by user_id.

Answer (score 1):

**High Level**

At some point there is a function along your route chain that is triggering the delayed email, you should just include the session (from `req.session`) in the task register. From there just make sure the proper user data is available for you to send the email (aka, user_id or user_email in the session data).

**More Detailed**

You need to think about how your middleware is handling this for a moment.

`app.use(session({` etc. is going to add a `session` object to your `req` object. Somewhere in your routes, you are processing another function (such as login or registration) after the `app.use
(session)` portion is called. So in the case of Gmail, you are calling an Oauth request to the Gmail api. They are going to return a user access token to you, which you can use to fetch their user data (such as email address). From there, you can attach their user data to your `req.session` object.

**A Simple Example (modify for your use)**

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'xxx',
  store: new pgSession({
    conString: config.db.url
  }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { maxAge: 24192000000 }
}));

app.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  // You'll have to write your own google client implementation :)
  var token = getGoogleAccessToken();

  // Again, left to you to write.
  var user_email = fetchUserGoogleEmail( token ); 

  var session = req.session;
  session.email = user_email;
  // Register heroku delayed task with session data.

  // Save user data and create account, etc.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code to do something similar

```
var email = require("emailjs");
var server = email.server.connect({
    user: "user@gmail.com",
    password: "password",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    ssl: true
});

var cron = require('node-schedule');

cron.scheduleJob({hour: 2, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 0}, function() {

    server.send({
        text: "i hope this works",
        from: "you <user@gmail.com>",
        to: "reciever <reciever@gmail.com>",
        subject: "My Email Subject"
    }, function(err, message) {
        //error handling
    });

});
```

hope this helps